# How to fix pixelated texture baking problem?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, texture-baking, unity

[image: pixelated texture]

I am using multiple 2k textures from the Materialx library and I want to import my model in unity game engine. While baking the textures its gets pixelated, I try to bake texture in 2k and even 4k resolution but the result is the same.

Blend:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cV8MTyJtGtFUbRzmOe8y4U23q7d9y6Hc/view?usp=sharing

These are my Render Properties & Output Properties.

[image: Output Properties]

[image: Render Properties]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you enable denoising? That should make it more smooth

Comment: Could you share the blend file?

Comment: Blend:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cV8MTyJtGtFUbRzmOe8y4U23q7d9y6Hc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Out of the box, Blender doesn't have any anti aliasing in baking. But some addon's do, like [Bystedts Blender Baker](https://3dbystedt.gumroad.com/l/JAqLT) (write zero in the price to get it for free, or any number if you want to reward the author).